# Windows Task Scheduler Powershell Script complete and restart

Tags: powershell, loops, scheduled-tasks, filesystemwatcher, taskscheduler

I have created a script that uses a FileSystemWatcher and creates a job. When a file is added to a folder it

1. Renames the newly added file
2. Moves the file to a new destination
3. Begins a downstream workflow

Once it’s done it ends the Job.

What I want to do is use Windows Task Scheduler to check that when the job completes to immediately run again. This way if one person drops a folder, that another person and can do the same.

ALSO If there is another way to have this work I am happy to use it.

I have tried to schedule the task to run but the lowest increment is 1 minute

I expect to have the filesystemwatcher running all the time. And once the script has finished I want it to start again.

Comment: can you post some code to see what you exactly want and what's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to start job when the event (file creation) occur, you can directly move the file and do whatever you want using `action` parameter.

Also, you don't have to restart the event, it is will keep running unless you manually unregister it, so you don't have to use task scheduler at all.

**Here's the code**

```
# set the folder you want to watch 
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "$home/Desktop/Folder"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

# start job when event is detected
$action = {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        # Step 1&2 (You can move the file and rename it with one step)
        Move-Item $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath -Destination $newPath
    } | Wait-Job
}

# Register and start the FileSystemWatcher 
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action $action
```

**Note** 
I used `Start-Job` in the code; However, you can omit it and put the code exactly in `$action`.

This code will register new FileSystemWatcher and will keep monitoring the folder for newly created file then move it to a new location.

**To stop the watcher**

```
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated
```

Look here for more information about [tracking changes to a folder using PowerShell](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/09/24/changes-to-a-folder-using-powershell.aspx)